# How to start redmine on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, redmine

Per https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/redmine installing redmine is as simple as apt-get install redmine. And it does appear to be installed. However I'm unable to access it or see it in the list of processes. How do I go about starting it?

I did try installing apache2 first, and apache2 works, but redmine is nowhere to be found.

Thanks!

Comment: `dpkg  -L redmine` will show the file list. Other redmine packages : http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&searchon=names&keywords=redmine

Answer (score 2):

From https://wiki.debian.org/redmine

### Install your database, e.g. postgresql (or don't, if you want to use sqlite)

```
apt install postgresql # or mysql-server
```

### Install redmine with support for your database of choice

```
apt install redmine redmine-pgsql # or redmine-mysql, or redmine-sqlite
```

Database configuration can be fully automated, courtesy of `dbconfig-common`.

### Configure web server

```
apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-passenger
cp /usr/share/doc/redmine/examples/apache2-passenger-host.conf \ 
  /etc/apache2/sites-available/redmine.conf
edit /etc/apache2/sites-available/redmine.conf
a2enmod passenger
a2ensite redmine.conf
service apache2 reload
```

Using passenger (`libapache2-mod-passenger`) is usually the easiest way. For using in a domain shared with other applications, base your config on `/usr/share/doc/redmine/examples/apache2-passenger-alias.conf` instead.

You can then log into Redmine http://servername (`ServerName` that you put in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/redmine.conf` and in your DNS or `hosts` file) with the following default admin account:

```
username: admin password: admin
```

Comment: Thank you! The setup page I found at https://www.redmineup.com/pages/help/installation/installing-redmine-on-ubuntu-16-04 assumed I wanted to use MySQL (ugh, why on earth would I?) and nginx (I might, but I don't).